# How to get number without thousand separator?

Tags: php

I have number ie `1,15,200` I want change to `115200` because when I divide it, it just divide 1 (before first comma)

eg : 
1,15,200 / 100

output : 0.01

suppose to output : 1152

Comment: the "1,15,200" is a string, remove the , and try again<

Comment: Hmm... http://codepad.org/91qHcOgX

Comment: @Jared Farrish: http://codepad.org/KACaDerY

Comment: What you're getting with the string number: http://codepad.org/xHTWg0qv

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$num = (int)str_replace(',', '', $string);
// or
$num = (int)preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
$num = filter_var('1,15,200', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Answer (score 3):

English notation without thousands separator

```
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
```