# How to use number_format without thousands separator and round function

Tags: php, rounding, separator, number-formatting

I have a doubt with how to use the number_format and round function together, this because I have an script to import all my supplier's products, but I need round the prices, for example:

Supplier's price: $1854.81
The price rounded: $1854.99 (This is the format that I want)
The price that my script print: $1,854.90

I tryed 3 PHP variant to do this:

Variant #1:

```
$preciosinr = 1854.81;
echo number_format(round($preciosinr*4)/4,2); //Print 1,854.90
```

Variant #2

```
$preciosinr = 1854.81;
$pos = 3 - floor(log10($preciosinr));
echo number_format(round($preciosinr,$pos)-0.10,2); //Print 1,854.75
```

Variant #3

```
$preciosinr = 1854.81;
number_format($preciosinr,2);
number_format(round($preciosinr,1),2);
number_format(round($preciosinr,0),2);
echo number_format(round($preciosinr,0)-0.01,2); //Print 1,854.99
```

As you can see all the variants prints the price with "," and I need the price without this because my system detect the price incorrectly.

I read in php.net that I need use the following sintaxis but I don't know how can integrate with my code.

```
// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$price=number_format(round($preciosinr,0)-0.01,2,'.','');

echo $price;
```

This should work

Answer (score 3):

I found it strange that the answer that was accepted is actually wrong.

Example case:

```php
// The input we want to check
$stringNumber = '7616.95';

// As suggested by accepted answer
$formatted = number_format(round($stringNumber,0)-0.01,2,'.','' );

echo $formatted; // Outputs: 7616.99
```

A better solution is found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7459107